# How can I darker in ImageView

Tags: kotlin, imageview

I need to change the image programmatically setting an type of "darker". I need do that bacause the text view in the recycler view need to be in contrast with the background image.
How can I put this effect?
I need something like this [image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a FrameLayout with 2 nested views inside, first add your ImageView and then add a view with gradient shape.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/dragon_ball_super" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shome_gradient_shape"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```